# How to validate a Django dynamic form?

Tags: django, forms, validation

I am creating a Quiz Generator application. How can I validate the form dynamically depending on the number of questions using Django Forms.

The application have 3 types of question. `Fill in the blank`, `Multiple choice`, and `True or False`.

I want to validate the form where if the question type is `Fill in the blank` it should validate it as a `CharField` and if it's `True or False` or `Multiple choice` it should validate it as a `ChoiceField`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create form with three (or more) inputs:

- `CharField` for your "fill in the blank" answer
- `BooleanField` for your "True or False" answer
- `ChoiceField` or `MultipleChoiceField` for your "Multiple choice" answer

All of fields shouldn't be marked as required. Now, you must pass to **init** of form value determining type of answer, override default **init** in form to save that value in form object for later use and for each field, you should make `clean_field` method (where field is name of your field) that will only perform validation if your answer-type value matches that field.

Comment: Hi! Do you have a code with that? I'm kinda new to Django